# .NET 6.0 Console app as a self-contained single file executable

Tags: c#, .net, package, .net-6.0

I want to create a single stand-alone executable which includes evertything needed to run - meaning the .NET 6.0 framework.

What I am expecting to see in PublishDir folder is a single executable file, but this appears not to be working. Nothing happens...

Can you create a truly single .NET6.0 executable for a console app which includes all the framework components it needs?

```
<PropertyGroup>
            <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
            <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
            <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
            <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
            <PublishDir>..\..\Binaries</PublishDir>
            <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
            <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
            <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
            <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
            <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
            <GeneratePackageOnBuild>False</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You want to also include the whole .net librairies ? why ?

Comment: the simple answer is because, the detailed answer is .NET6.0 not installed on the machine and will take to long (corporate) to get installed.

Comment: It worked for me with your config, only the exe and pdb

Comment: so just done it with a console app and it didn't work, but when I ran 'dotnet publish' from command line it built to a single executable of size approx 57 Mb. Was the executable you were able to generate roughly that size?

Comment: but... If you were not using `dotnet publish`, how were you publishing before? That's the way to publish (from the command line). Yes, the exe was about that size

Comment: I'm not, I'm jsut trying to do this from VS2022, I thought I should be able to annotation the csproj file with the correct values and the build process would automatically do it

Comment: From VS I always configure throught VS publosh interface. There you can configure a sel-contained single exe file.

Comment: ah, me old school .net, so using the 'Publish Selection' under Build menu - thanks very much

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Comment: Also, the 57mb is about right, as you're bundling the whole framework. You can try `<PublishTrimmed>true` to trim unused code from the framework, but I've had mixed results (some apps refused to run) during the .NET5 times and never tried it again since.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vs 2022, To the left of the run button, there's an any cpu dropdown, and to the left of that, there's a dropdown where you can select debug or release. Select release and then press cntrl + b, wait for it to build, then naviagte to your file under c:\user\source\repos\file\bin\release and find the exe there. Does this help?