# VB.NET Application with .NET 6.0 Single File .exe issue

Tags: vb.net, publish

I've run into a bit of an issue that's left me a little confused.

Previously when i would finish a program, i would just grab the .exe from the Debug or Build folder. I could then copy, paste, move etc. the file whenever i want and it would work as intended. (my programs are not deployed throughout an organization or anything, they are very simple, for a couple of PCs only).

Now, I have finished a console program that just copies certain files to another location as a backup. I've gone to grab the .exe and noticed a heap of files in the Release folder. The below is an example from another program (which does reference some addons), but still in the past this used to be contains in one .exe
[image]If i copy / move the .exe to another location it doesn't work. It doesn't do anything, no error messages it just doesn't run.

I've gone to compare a previous program (which is very similar) and the only thing i can see that's different is the .NET Framework, moving from 4.8 to 6.0.

I did find an option when publishing the code to make it a Single File Application, but the file size become very large. The previous Console program was 46kb. The new one is 2.6mb, yet there is half the amount of code and still wont work if moved to another location.

So my question is, how can i have it so that it was previous, where I can grab the .exe from the bin and its "portable".

Ive looked at a few posts, namely
[.NET 6.0 Console app as a self-contained single file executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041906/net-6-0-console-app-as-a-self-contained-single-file-executable)
[Single file application .NET Core 6.0 fails to generate bundles, if the file is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348334/single-file-application-net-core-6-0-fails-to-generate-bundles-if-the-file-is)

But it doesn't help in my situation. I can change the .net framework back if need be, but it seems a bit crazy to me that .NET 6.0 seems to require all files to be in a set location where 4.8 does not?

Comment: You may consider referring to the official MS documentation. However, I'm not sure that you'll find any references to copying a single _.exe_ file. Ideally, one creates an installer and installs one's application on the desired computers. The following may be helpful: [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) and [Tutorial: Publish a .NET console application using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

Comment: In .NET 6+, the *executable* is a dll, the .exe is the *launcher*, then you have a couple of JSON files. If you don't have any external / third-party packages (and the runtime is installed in the target machine), that's all you need -- What *heap of files* do you see? What is *the Build folder*?

Comment: Build = Release folder, sorry old habbits with some wrong terminology. I have added an image to show what is Published.

With the comment above, would i be right in saying that .net 4.8 can be contained in 1 .exe but .net 6.0 requires more files to run? Sounds a bit backwards?

Comment: It's not about the .NET version, it's about the fact that you have added multiple optional packages to the Project. Some of them may have brought in other required packages (stuff that is not part of the runtime) -- You can of course use the `Publish => Deployment Mode`, setting it to Self-contained and also tick the `Produce single file` option to generate a single executable file -- When you add packages through NuGet Package Manager or the automated VS tools, you of course have to include those packages when you deploy, no way around it

Comment: When selecting both of those options, the filesize of the .exe becomes 63MB?

Comment: Again, you have added to the Project optional / third-party packages (that, as mentioned, bring in other packages they require). How did you think this would end up? Those libraries need to be part of the distribution, if your Project references them. Maybe you have added packages that you don't actually need? If that's the case, then remove them, the size of the packaged app will also decrease. If you need them all...

Comment: If you are going from 4.8 to 6.0 then you are switching from .NET Framework to .NET Core! Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967697/make-net-core-console-app-a-single-exe

Comment: P.S. When I publish Hello, World as a single EXE I get an exe that is 57MB, this is normal for .NET Core